# Require cycle: node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js uninitialized values

Tags: node.js, react-native, xmlhttprequest, node-modules, rn-fetch-blob

Require cycle: node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/index.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/polyfill/XMLHttpRequest.js -> node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `rn-fetch-blob` Library,

all these 4 files: `Blob.js`, `Fetch.js`, `FileReader.js`, `XMLHttpRequest.js`

Comment this line:

```js
import RNFetchBlob from '../index.js'
```

Then, add below line:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'; 

const RNFetchBlob = NativeModules.RNFetchBlob
```

Comment: It's generally considered poor practice to edit library source locally without using a proper patching process like `patch-package`.  If that library updates, you're right back with the problem you had and may not remember what you changed.  Also, `0.13.0-beta.2` contains this fix. [Relevant Issue](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/183) | [Relevant PR](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/pull/688)